# How does "presumir" work in this sentence?

Tags: gramática

I came across a comment on Facebook that went like this:

> **Mira te presumo mis dientes de marfil.**

According to Google the sentence translates as:

> *I think my teeth look like ivory.*

Although I know **presumir** means *to presume*, **dientes** means *teeth*, and **marfil** means *ivory*, I am still having a hard time understanding the syntax. Why does the sentence start with **mirar**? And shouldn't we have **como** instead of **de**? Another thing, what's the **te** there for when the sentence has nobody in the second person?

Comment: Without the context of the sentence, none of your questions can be answered easily.  To everyone except you this is just a random sentence; horribly translated by a robot.

Comment: The context is that of a woman talking about her pearly white teeth. The original Spanish sentence is what she wrote. The English translation is from Google Translate.

Comment: There is a writing problem that difficult to understand the sentence. The expression _"mira"_ here is used as an phatic interjection, a warning. The right thing would _Mira, te presumo mis dientes de perfil_, separated by comma or dot.

Comment: **Presumir** and *presume* are indeed cognates and both in English and Spanish they have the meaning of *anticipate*. However, in Spanish the word **presumir** also means *brag* or *show off*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mira te presumo mis dientes de marfil`

This sentence translates to something along this lines of

> And now, without further ado, I present to you my ivory teeth

or

> Hey! Check out my ivory teeth!

The use of presumir in this sentence is used to express vanity...

> 3. intr. Dicho de una persona: Cuidar mucho su arreglo para parecer atractiva.
>      http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=hjrhXgxCHDXX2nXPJtbi

So really, it is like literally saying

> `Look, I am showing off my ivory teeth to you`

Comment: So, would you say the "mira" here is an imperative?

Comment: Yes.  Mira is idenpendent of te presumo.

Comment: Also, isn't "presumir" the Spanish for "to presume"? How can it translate as "to present"?

Comment: Presumir has other meanings when it's intransitive

Comment: It's interesting that the usage here is transitive.  Googling around I see that the verb is actively used transitively.  Time for an update for the entry (in the dictionary).  It's almost being used more as a synonym for *estrenar*

Comment: And in fact, that's exactly what the DPD says: "2. En el español mexicano presumir se usa también como transitivo con el sentido de ‘mostrar [algo o a alguien] con orgullo o presunción’: «Decidió visitarlo lo más pronto posible, pues quería presumirle su incipiente bigote» (Esquivel Deseo [Méx. 2001])."  The D.AA. lists the usage as not just Mexican, but also Guatamalan, Nicaraugan, Ecuatorian, Peruvian, Bolivian, Paraguayan, and Argentine."

Comment: @guifa +1 for helping me learn something new and interesting today! It's this transitive usage of "presumir" that was bothering me because in English you wouldn't normally use "to presume" this way. Thanks.

Comment: You should never compare Spanish to English.  Just because something doesn't sound correct in English does not mean the same for Spanish; or any other language for the matter.

Comment: Also, as guifa says, it's used in latin-america.  That sentence would make absolutely no sense in Spain.

Answer (score -1):

Mira te presumo mis dientes de marfil. is grammatically incorrect and makes no sense in Spanish.  It's either a typo and the person meant to write 'presento' or he doesn't know howo to use the verb 'presumir'

A correct sentence using 'presumir de' would be: 'Presumo de dientes de marfil', which means 'I boast of having white-ivory teeth'.

If he wanted to use the verb 'presento', as in 'Mira, te presento mis dientes de marfil' the sentence would mean 'Look, meet my white-ivory teeth'

Comment: The question wasn't about grammatical correctness.  The OP saw this on Facebook, a discourse community.  English has internet slang as well, `Idk`, `I wanna`, `For the win`, et cetera.

Comment: I wrote my answer from a Spanish point of view.  That sentence does not exist here, in Spain.  It isn't used in normal street language, and it isn't used as internet slang by Spanish people.  I just read the above comment of it being used in Latin America, which I didn't know, as I don't speak latin-american Spanish ;)